# No tables created in the MySQL database in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Here is my Application.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =
    {JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserFrontApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserFrontApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Contents of application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.userFront</groupId>
<artifactId>userfront</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>UserFront</name>
<description>User frontend for online banking</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The application runs fine but no tables are created.

User class that has to be stored in database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;
}
```

Comment: do you get any exception or stack trace. suppose you take a look at sample projects [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot)

Comment: what s the package where your User class is in?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect. you need to update dialect as per your database, update these two properties.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main class, try adding

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"packagename_where_entity_class_is_present"})
```

Hope it works!

OR

You can try reordering the packages i.e. for example, if your main class is in the package com.main, then let your entity class be in the package com.main.entity

Answer (score 0):

yes, check your entity class and application class(where the main function is present ) if both are in different packages then move your entity class to the package where the application class is present.